# Distribution function of Sum of IID Exponentiation Variables of Variable amount

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

So I'm trying to determine the distribution function of a random variable, S, give:

  $N \sim Geo(\frac{1}{1+\lambda}) $

  $S_i \sim Exp(\mu), \forall i\in [0,N]$

  $S = \Sigma^{N}_{i=0}S_i$

  $S = 0$ if $N=0$

Taking the approach of first evaluating $P(S>x)$, I know that the sum of n exponentiation distributions is a Gamma distribution and by the Law of Total Probability:

  $P(S>x)=\Sigma^{\infty}_{i=0}P(S>x|N=n)\times P(N=n)$

  $=\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=0}[[(\frac{1}{1+\lambda})(\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda})^n][e^{-\mu x}\Sigma^{n-1}_{r=0}\frac{(\mu x)^r}{r!}]]$ (I think)

But I'm completely stuck at that ... if it's even correct.

Comment: What's $S$ if $N=0$?

Comment: Note that $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{1+\lambda}\left(\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)^ne^{-\mu x}\sum^{n-1}_{r=0}\frac{(\mu x)^r}{r!}=e^{-\mu x}\sum^{\infty}_{r=0}\frac{(\mu x)^r}{r!}\sum^{\infty}_{n=r+1}\frac{1}{1+\lambda}\left(\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)^n$$ is $$e^{-\mu x}\sum^{\infty}_{r=0}\frac{(\mu x)^r}{r!}\left(\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)^{r+1}=\ldots$$ and do not forget to use `\sum` to denote sums instead of `\Sigma`.